# App stopped working: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable'

Tags: java, android, rippledrawable

I'm new to android and i develop an app which use Google places autocomplete with recycle view.
when I try to run the app, it's not working and shows

> Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable',
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

There are questions related to this, but any of them do not solve my problem.

Here is my activity_search_bus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.busgeni.busgeni.SearchBus">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/idsource_txt"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/write_text"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/source_point"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="#c6c6c6" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/iddestination_txt"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/write_text"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/destination_point"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="#c6c6c6" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="60dp"
        android:background="#1A237E"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/search_button"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_source"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/idsource_txt"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_des"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iddestination_txt"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

search_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:id="@+id/idsearch_row"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@drawable/write_text"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/locationimg"
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/locationimg"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

SearchBus.java

```
package com.example.busgeni.busgeni;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.busgeni.busgeni.Adapters.AT_Adapter;
import com.example.busgeni.busgeni.Listeners.Recycler_Listener;
import com.example.busgeni.busgeni.Utility.Constants;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

public class SearchBus extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener
{
    GoogleApiClient my_client;

    private static final LatLngBounds my_Bounds = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-0, 0), new LatLng(0, 0));

    private EditText my_source, my_destination;
    private RecyclerView my_Recycle_source, my_Recycle_destination;
    private LinearLayoutManager my_Layout_Manager;
    private AT_Adapter my_AT_Adapter;

    private static Button search_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        buildGoogleApiClient();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_bus);

        my_source = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idsource_txt);
        my_destination = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.iddestination_txt);

        my_AT_Adapter =  new AT_Adapter(this, R.layout.search_row,
                my_client, my_Bounds, null);

        my_Recycle_source=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_source);
        my_Recycle_destination=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_des);
        my_Layout_Manager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        my_Recycle_source.setLayoutManager(my_Layout_Manager);
        my_Recycle_source.setAdapter(my_AT_Adapter);
        my_Recycle_destination.setLayoutManager(my_Layout_Manager);
        my_Recycle_destination.setAdapter(my_AT_Adapter);

       // delete.setOnClickListener(this);

        my_source.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                if (!s.toString().equals("") && my_client.isConnected())
                {
                    my_AT_Adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                } else if(!my_client.isConnected())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e(Constants.PlacesTag,Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED);
                }

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        my_destination.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                if (!s.toString().equals("") && my_client.isConnected())
                {
                    my_AT_Adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                } else if(!my_client.isConnected())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e(Constants.PlacesTag,Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED);
                }

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        my_Recycle_source.addOnItemTouchListener( new Recycler_Listener(this, new Recycler_Listener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        final AT_Adapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = my_AT_Adapter.getItem(position);
                        final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                        Log.i("TAG", "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);
                        /*
                             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional details about the place.
                         */

                        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                                .getPlaceById(my_client, placeId);
                        placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                                if(places.getCount()==1){
                                    //Do the things here on Click.....
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(places.get(0).getLatLng()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Constants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Log.i("TAG", "Clicked: " + item.description);
                        Log.i("TAG", "Called getPlaceById to get Place details for " + item.placeId);
                    }
                })
        );

        my_Recycle_destination.addOnItemTouchListener( new Recycler_Listener(this, new Recycler_Listener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        final AT_Adapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = my_AT_Adapter.getItem(position);
                        final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                        Log.i("TAG", "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);
                        /*
                             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional details about the place.
                         */

                        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                                .getPlaceById(my_client, placeId);
                        placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                                if(places.getCount()==1){
                                    //Do the things here on Click.....
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(places.get(0).getLatLng()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Constants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Log.i("TAG", "Clicked: " + item.description);
                        Log.i("TAG", "Called getPlaceById to get Place details for " + item.placeId);
                    }
                })
        );

        onClickButtonListener();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }*/

    public void onClickButtonListener() {
        search_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);
        search_btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.busgeni.busgeni.SearchResult");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!my_client.isConnected() && !my_client.isConnecting()){
            Log.v("Google API","Connecting");
            my_client.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(my_client.isConnected()){
            Log.v("Google API","Dis-Connecting");
            my_client.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.v("Google API Callback", "Connection Done");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.v("Google API Callback", "Connection Suspended");
        Log.v("Code", String.valueOf(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /*if(v==delete){
            my_source.setText("");
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v("Google API Callback","Connection Failed");
        Log.v("Error Code", String.valueOf(connectionResult.getErrorCode()));
        Toast.makeText(this, Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        my_client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At which line does it crash?

Comment: I think it crashes at my_Recycle_destination.setLayoutManager(my_Layout_Manager); in search_bus.java file

Comment: You can't use the same LayoutManager on both views. Create a separate one for each

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Comment: I posted it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the same LayoutManager for two different RecyclerViews. Create a new instance for each, and use them separately.